# Unable to start kafka server

Tags: apache-kafka

I am a student and trying to learn about Apache kafka. I was able to install kafka  from http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html. But when I am trying to start the server, I get below error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<verbosegc xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/j9/verbosegc"  version="R28_Java8_SR1_20150410_1531_B243669_CMPRSS">

JVMJ9VM007E Command-line option unrecognised: -Xloggc:/usr/local/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log
</verbosegc>
```

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

My Java version is :

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6480sr1fp1-20150603_01(SR1 FP1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References      20150410_243669 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_Java8_SR1_20150410_1531_B243669
JIT  - tr.r14.java_20150402_88976.03
GC   - R28_Java8_SR1_20150410_1531_B243669_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20150410_243669)
JCL - 20150601_01 based on Oracle jdk8u45-b13
```

The issue looks similar to http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/dev/163wdvk75y/jira-created-kafka-3476-xloggc-is-not-recognised-by-ibm-java but there is no solution there

Answer (score 0):

According to the the link you gave, this is a problem specific to IBM Java. The solution suggested there worked for me:

```
export KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xverbosegclog:$TRACE_DIR/server-gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps"
export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS="-server -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```